# Choosing file via JFrame and returning pathToFile to main class

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to create a simple form, which will allow user to choose a file and then I want to work with this file in main class. But I've got an error "Variable frame is accessed from inner class". Ok, I've read that I must make a variable final, which gives me  "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'frame'", which is right. Reading stackoverflow again, I found out that I must put the defining variable before main procedure. But here I stacked - I don't think it's a good solution since I never see any code examples that define variables this way. Still I tried and got the error.

```
public class HelloWorld {
//ExcelChooseFileFrame frame;
public static void main(String[] args)  {
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
final ExcelChooseFileFrame frame;
        public void run() {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            frame = new ExcelChooseFileFrame();//Cannot assign a value to final variable 'frame'
        }
    });
}
```

ExcelChooseFileFrame

```
public class ExcelChooseFileFrame  extends JFrame {
File file;
public ExcelChooseFileFrame(){
    super("Choose excel");

                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

                final JLabel label = new JLabel("Choosed file");
                label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                panel.add(label);

                panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));

                JButton button = new JButton("Show JFileChooser");
                button.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                        int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");
                        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                            file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
//                                System.out.println(file.getPath());
                            setVisible(false);
                            dispose();
            }
        }
    });

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260, 220));
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
public String getPathToFile() {
    return file.getPath();
}
}
```

I understand that's a pretty simple task, but nevertheless I spend several hours trying to solve it and still unsuccessfull. Please, point me, how to get the frame or file object from main.
Thank you!

Comment: If you declare frame where it is, it doesn't need to be final. Only if you declared it outside the runnable would it need to be final.

Answer (score 0):

In `HelloWorld`, initialize the variable on the line where it is declared:

```
public final ExcelChooseFileFrame frame = new ExcelChooseFileFrame()
```

then eliminate the assignment in the code. And it only needs to be public if you expect to refer to it from some other class, outside the package.